# why this is not a right Producer consumer model and what causes the error when I use stl queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading

there will be a error after the application run a period of time at the line `delete busMsg` .I don't understand how the error came about.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

CRITICAL_SECTION  m_csReceivedMsgQueue;
HANDLE    m_hReceivedDataEvent;
HANDLE  m_hEventStop;
queue<CBusMsg* > m_qReceivedMsgQueue;

class CBusMsg
 {
    public:
    CBusMsg(WORD  nAgentID, WORD nAgentExclue,  BYTE* pBuf,int nLen)
    {
       m_nAgentID=nAgentID;
       m_nAgentExclue=nAgentExclue;
       m_nLen=nLen;
       m_pBuf=new BYTE[m_nLen];
       memcpy(m_pBuf,pBuf,nLen);
    }
   ~CBusMsg()
   {
       if (m_pBuf!=NULL)
          delete[] m_pBuf;
   }
   WORD  m_nAgentID;   //0:群发，其它:单播
   WORD  m_nAgentExclue;   
   BYTE* m_pBuf;
   int   m_nLen;
};
UINT SendhreadProc( LPVOID pParam)
{   
    HANDLE  hWaitObjList[2]={m_hEventStop,m_hReceivedDataEvent};
    bool haveData = false;
    DWORD dwWaitRes;
    for(;;)
     {
        if(haveData)//如果还有未处理的数据不等待内核对象直接返回
        {
          dwWaitRes=::WaitForMultipleObjects(2,hWaitObjList,FALSE,0);   
        }
        else//如果没有未处理的数据不等待内核对象直接返回
        {
        dwWaitRes=::WaitForMultipleObjects(2,hWaitObjList,FALSE,200);   
        }
        if((dwWaitRes-WAIT_OBJECT_0)==0)//,索引为0的内核对象被触发，也就是停止线程被触发
       {
           break;
       }
        haveData = false;
       try
       {
           EnterCriticalSection(&m_csReceivedMsgQueue);
           if(m_qReceivedMsgQueue.empty())
          {
            LeaveCriticalSection(&m_csReceivedMsgQueue);
            continue;
          }
        CBusMsg*& busMsg = m_qReceivedMsgQueue.front();//取队首元素
        m_qReceivedMsgQueue.pop();//弹出队首元素
        if(NULL==busMsg)
        {
            LeaveCriticalSection(&m_csReceivedMsgQueue);
            continue;
        }
        //ASSERT(busMsg->m_nLen<=0);
        //pAgent->SetData(busMsg->m_pBuf,busMsg->m_nLen);
        haveData = !m_qReceivedMsgQueue.empty();
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_csReceivedMsgQueue);
        //**************There is the error********************/
        delete busMsg;
       //********************************************************/
        //busMsg = NULL;
        //ProcessData(pAgent);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_csReceivedMsgQueue);
    }
}
//delete pAgent;
return 0;
}


UINT PushData( LPVOID pParam)
{
BYTE pPacket[1000];
memset(pPacket,0,1000);
for (int i=0;i<100000;i++)
{
    CBusMsg *pBusMsg;
    pPacket[0]= i;
    pBusMsg=new CBusMsg(i,0,pPacket,1000);
    TRACE("请求向队列加消息\n");
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_csReceivedMsgQueue);
    TRACE("开始向队列加消息\n");
    m_qReceivedMsgQueue.push(pBusMsg);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_csReceivedMsgQueue);
    SetEvent(m_hReceivedDataEvent);

}
return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&m_csReceivedMsgQueue);

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);


    m_hReceivedDataEvent =::CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL);
    m_hEventStop=::CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL);

    //创建发送线程
    CWinThread*  m_pSendThread=AfxBeginThread(SendhreadProc,NULL,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL);
    m_pSendThread->m_bAutoDelete=FALSE;
    m_pSendThread->ResumeThread();

    CWinThread*  processThread=AfxBeginThread(PushData,NULL,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL);
    processThread->m_bAutoDelete=FALSE;
    processThread->ResumeThread();

    char str[1000];
    cin.getline(str,900);
    return nRetCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be here

```
CBusMsg*& busMsg = m_qReceivedMsgQueue.front();//取队首元素
m_qReceivedMsgQueue.pop();//弹出队首元素
```

You take a reference to the pointer from the queue.
Then you pop the queue making the reference invalid.
Which will make the program crash some times.
This might make you happier

```
CBusMsg* busMsg = m_qReceivedMsgQueue.front();//取队首元素
m_qReceivedMsgQueue.pop();//弹出队首元素
```

Why does it crash, because the address that is referenced might be reused for something different before you get to

```
delete busMsg;
```

You release the lock just before the delete and in that time another can put something new in the queue using the same address for example if the queue is empty after the `.pop`. Then the delete doesn't delete the original referenced message but the new one it is referenced to.

Comment: Yes.if i don't take a reference,it don't crash.But why it did't crash everytime?Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Yeah,I get it.Thank you very much ！